# Powershell - Get last modified file's parent directory name

Tags: powershell

I have a couple of folders and all of them have a Log folder inside them and the log files.
Only one of the folder gets its log files modified. And I need to retrieve its top parent directory name.

I can't use `Sort-Object LastWriteTime` because whenever the log gets updated - only the log file gets its last modified time updated. The `Log` and the `top parent folder` doesn't have their `lastwritetime` updated at all.

How can I do this?

```
Folder1\Log\filename1.log
Folder2\Log\filename3.log -> Assume this is the latest one that got its log file updated.
Folder3\Log\filename5.log
Folder4\Log\filename2.log
Folder5\Log\filename6.log
```

I want to get the "Folder2" as the output

Comment: What is your code so far?

Comment: The old code I had was just sort-based on LastWriteTime and then use that. But new deployment has changed the structure of directories. So not sure if this is possible, but I'm thinking of sorting with lastWriteTime and Select 5 directories and then loop through those 5 directories and find the latest log file updated directory and return it.

Comment: Note that the folder1, 2 and others are old versions but sometimes we might revert to old versions and then it'll have latest log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using `Get-ChildItem`, filter for '*.log' files and recurse through the root folder where the subfolders are.

Then sort on the files LastWriteTime property, select the newest one and take the folder name from that:

```
$rootFolder = 'X:\TheRootFolderWhereTheSubFoldersAre'
Split-Path -Path ((Get-ChildItem -Path $rootFolder -Filter '*.log' -File -Recurse | 
                   Sort-Object LastWriteTime | Select-Object -Last 1).DirectoryName) -Leaf
```